# Yii2 Url::to returns local IP instead of public server name

Tags: yii2

I have an application developped using **Yii Framework v2**.

In one of the pages, images are included, but don't display properly as their ***url contains the local server IP address***, and not the public server name. For example, I have `img` tag with `src`  like https://10.0.0.20/path/to/image.jpg.

As I understand it (I'm not the one who developped this), the URL is set using the following function, from backend\modules\news\models\News.php:

```
public function getImageUrl()
{
    $path = \Yii::getAlias('@uploads/news/') . $this->image;

    if (!is_file($path)) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return Url::to(\Yii::getAlias('@uploads/news-rel/' . $this->image), true);
    }
}
```

It is called in a file frontend/widgets/news/views/_item.php with:

```
<?php

use kartik\helpers\Html;
use common\helpers\DateHelper;
use yii\helpers\StringHelper;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\modules\news\models\News */

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
?>

<div class="news-item-image col-md-3">
    <?php if ($model->image): ?>
        <?= Html::img($model->getImageUrl()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="news-item-content col-md-9">
    <div class="news-item-content-title"><?= $model->title ?></div>
    <div class="news-item-content-date">
        <?= strftime('%e %B %G', strtotime($model->publishDate)) ?>        
    </div>
    <div class="news-item-content-body"><?= StringHelper::truncateWords(strip_tags($model->body), 20) ?></div>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Read more'), ['/news/view', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'news-item-content-read-more']) ?>
</div>
```

In other places, same kind of code is used, and return a proper url (https://www.example.com/path/to/resource).
What should I look after to debug this ?

EDIT1: @uploads alias is defined in backend/config/bootstrap.php with this lines:

```
/*Yii::setAlias('@uploads', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../web') . '/uploads');
Yii::setAlias('uploads/images-rel', '/uploads/images');
Yii::setAlias('uploads/editor-rel', '/uploads/editor');*/
```

It is the same alias that is used in many other places, and returns urls with server name.
Thanks
Franck

Comment: are you using the same alias in other pages too?

Comment: `@uploads` is not a predefined alias, how are you setting that alias?

Comment: Michal is right, check your config dir files for `@uploads` Alias definition.

Comment: @alci try `Yii::setAlias('@uploads', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/uploads');`in your bootstrap file

Comment: @indra shastri I replaced the original alias with yours, and the bahviour remains the same (but also it works as well in most places)... BUT I noticed something interesting: in a local copy of the site, the news images url are well written... so, can it be related with the config of my nginx reverse proxy frontend ? (what is strange is that most urls are ok, only the images in news are bad...)

Comment: Turns out that setting "proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;" in my nginx reverse proxy solved the issue... What is strange is that it mostly worked everywhere in the site, except for these images... don't know why.
By the way, can't (yet ?) post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

check your `config/web.php` file.

Look for the [hostInfo](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$hostInfo-detail)

Or set it up yourself. It's going to alter your Urls.

Also:

> When $scheme is specified (either a string or true), an absolute URL with host info (obtained from yii\web\UrlManager::$hostInfo) will be returned. If $url is already an absolute URL, its scheme will be replaced with the specified one.

Source: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-url